# Scala Client Library for Apache OpenWhisk

Tags: scala, openwhisk

Is there a Scala client library for [Apache OpenWhisk](https://openwhisk.apache.org/)?

Comment: There is Java client so ?

Comment: You might have better luck if you ask on their mailing list https://openwhisk.apache.org/community.html#mailing-lists

Comment: @cchantep I was hoping for an interface designed more specifically for Scala. Plus, its documentation doesn't seem to be in good shape at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn’t an Apache community supported Scala client. There is quite a bit to seed such an implementation from the Scala REST and CLI bindings defined by this interface https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/fcbe9ca83829f2194b47f7c61a166396838c6a44/tests/src/test/scala/common/WskOperations.scala#L163 but it is not a standalone client.

If it’s something you’re interested in contributing to the project and community, you should reach out on the Apache project dev list as noted in one of the comments above.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the situation. I'll see if I can contribute anything to the project.